# Paypal Sandbox Access Token not Found in Cache

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having a persisting issue with the Paypal access token for the sandbox environment where I continually get the error,

```
Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing- 
agreements` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: 
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access Token not found in cache"}
```

I am not sure where to go as this is a new token that is being generated and used just prior to running the API call. Everything was working normal until this began giving me issues a couple of nights ago. It seems to return this error for about 30 minutes or so until the token begins working. My issue is that once I switch to the live version, I do not want there to be this error while the new token is "processing" as the tokens are going to automatically update (or doing whatever the issue is).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed (obviously once I go for help). It was caching the old token and then not using the new token with the request. I just needed to add a line to update the config files upon updating the token.

Comment: Hi Ian, I am currently experimenting the same. Paypal payment is working on localhost, but it is failing on live. Even I am developing on java, please, can you explain this sentence: "I just needed to add a line to update the config files upon updating the token". Regards.

Comment: When I was updating the token, I needed to cache the env file (for PHP) to the config files. I needed to run “php artisan config:cache” on the update so the key would be updated.

Comment: @Im2a Hi Im2a, I have the same issue when integrate paypal rest api into Java springboot. Do you fix the issue on your side?

Comment: Anyone with SpringBoot solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being with Laravel's configuration caching from the env file. I just ran `php artisan config:cache` and it fixed itself. I added to the command

```php
Artisan::call('config:cache');
```

and this fixed all of my issues.